# How can I change the game save directory?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

By default game saves are there in my documents folder. I want it to change the save directory to something else, how can I do that?

Comment: What do you need this for? If you're, say, seeking to back up your data with Dropbox -- or anyway looking for a way to keep copies of your savefiles in a different folder -- I have a way. Otherwise I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: good guess. i am currently doing this in dropbox using `junction`.

Comment: that's exactly what I was going to propose to you :) Put it in an answer and you have my upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method:**

1. Goto C:\Documents and settings\ *User Name*\
2. Right Click + Drag My Documents folder to any other drive (D:, E:, F: etc)
3. (You can also move Favorites and Desktop folder to other drives as well)

All your documents will be then saved there.

**Second Method:**

Use [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

1. Download and install [Hard Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html)
2. Right click *NFS Most Wanted* folder in *My Documents* and *Pick Link Source*
3. Go to the required folder where you want to save and then pick *Drop as... Junction* from the right click menu.

***Save them Online:***

Use [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) with [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/link/20.Zsa_7Y8V1N/NjIzNDg4NjA3Nw).

1. Download and install [Hard Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html)
2. Right click *NFS Most Wanted* folder in *My Documents* and *Pick Link Source*
3. Go to the *My Dropbox* folder and then pick *Drop as... Junction* from the right menu.

Comment: The question doesn't mention dropbox, and I think this answer should reflect that.

Comment: So dropbox should be the second method.